# Complicated problem in scala list filteration

Tags: scala

I have 3 Lists from 3 files I want to filter their values according to each other

```
val Info = List(List(155 , 2 , 33 , 77 ) , List( 248 , 8 , 155 , 66), . . .)

val The_Range = List (List(155) , List(248) , List(147) , . . .)

val Detail = List ( List ( 2 , MIT , 55 , 77 , 99)
                  , List ( 5 , Stanford , 77 , 99 , 100), . . .)
```

every **list** inside the List represents a ROW from Data

I want to Filter **Info** List accordint to **Range** and **Detail** Like  This

if **first elements** in List **Info** Like  (155)  and  (248)  exists inside **The_Range** List then return its **list (the whole ROW)**

Then the **new Filtered List** Check if  (Second element like (2)) in List **Info**  exists  in List **Detail** ( the First element like (2)  )

and ( The Third element ) in **Info** > ( The Third element ) in **Detail** List

**Return the ROW**

Comment: A `List[List[Any]]` is a bad idea, have you considered parsing each _row_ into a **case class** that better defines your model? - In ant case, what have you tried to do the filtering? - PS: Another advice, parse the _"the range"_ and _"details"_ into `Maps` so searching for a key on those is **O(1)**.